# Display text into div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text-editor

The bootstrap editor is working good, but I want to display the entered data into a div with the id: `enclousere`. It works fine but the data should display like this:

> Enclouser:
>
> 1. first enclouser
> 2. second enclouser
> 3. 3rd enclouser

**But it displays like:**

```
Enclouser:<div><ol><li>first enclouser</li><li>second enclouser</li><li>3rd enclouser</li></ol></div>
```

**My model:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModale" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
           <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Enclosure</h4>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-body sol">
              <textarea id="textareaIDe" class="form-control"></textarea>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" id="savedatae" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
           </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**MY JQuery:**

```
$('#myModala').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#textareaIDe').focus();
})
$("#savedatae").click(function(){
  var message = $('.sol .Editor-editor').html();
  alert(message);
  $('#enclousere').text(message);
  //alert(message);
});
```

**Tag used to display:**

```
<div class="fsize" id="enclousere"></div>
```

Comment: `$('#enclousere').text(message);` should be `$('#enclousere').html(message);`

Comment: @mplungjan thanks it works for me

Comment: @Fred-ii- i will remove tagged PHP

Comment: @Dev - please delete

Comment: Actual duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288548/jquery-turn-text-tags-to-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.html(message);
```

Instead of

```
.text(message);
```

Comment: Not worth an answer. Already answered in the comment. Should be closed as typo

Comment: @mplungjan I answered in the same time of the answer, and I don't understand why this is not an answer, he asked a question and I typed and answer, .html instead of .text is not a typo. Or maybe I don't get it right ? And if it's the case, I apologize

Comment: It belongs in the "typo" reason for closing. It is not worth anything to other users.

Comment: the text is _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: Also it is identical to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288548/jquery-turn-text-tags-to-html-tags

Comment: @mplungjan Ok, thanks for clarifying, I won't do the same mistake in the future.